# Removing header on chapter page

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, chapters, fancyhdr

I am using the `fancyhdr` package where from what I understand the default is no header on the chapter pages, but I still have the header displaying the section name on all my chapter pages. I would like to still have the footer with the page number, but not the header.

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}} % set the \leftmark
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[RO, LE]{\leftmark} % 1. sectionname
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}
```

Comment: Wellcome to SE! Please prowide minimal working example, a short document, which we can compile and exhibits  your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Since `\chapter` uses `\thispagestyle{plain}`, the `\fancypagestyle{plain}` redefinition must disable the `\fancyhead[RO,LE]{...}` from `fancy` style, i.e. say `\fancyhead{}` in `\fancypagestyle{plain}{...}`.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}} % set the \leftmark
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[RO, LE]{\leftmark} % 1. sectionname
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhead{}%
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}


\chapter{First}
\section{First section}
\blindtext[10]
\chapter{Second}

\section{First section in 2nd chapter}
\blindtext[10]


\end{document}
```

[image]